# spotify controlled by arduino

Tags: arduino, controller, music, player

I want to build a [spotify](http://www.spotify.com/) controller [next song button for the moment] with Arduino

to build something like this song changer [physical song changer](https://vimeo.com/39491102#)

What do I need to control my spotify? using a windows machine? [using processing?]

the examples I have seen use a mac and AppleScript [spotify box](http://awards.ixda.org/entry/2012/spotify-box)

so do I need to connect to the [spotify  API with Processing](https://sites.google.com/site/mtwebapis/students/rick-companje/processing-parsing-json) ??

do you guys know of an example to do this?, if not, what would be the best way to accomplish it?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that you make your arduino behave like a usb keyboard, and then add a keyboard shortcut for the features you want like "next song".

I think you can use the LUFA usb lib on the arduino.